# How to get text inside of an XML node using Python elementtree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a strangely formatted XML file:

```
<list name="List1">
  <listitem>
    <variable name="name1">text1</variable>
    <variable name="name2">text2</variable>
  </listitem>
  <listitem>
    <variable name="name1">text3</variable>
    <variable name="name2">text4</variable>
  </listitem>
  ...
</list>
```

The following code

```
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.findall('listitem'):
    vars = item.find('variable')
    print(vars.attrib)
```

returns:

```
{'name': 'name1'}
{'name': 'name1'}
{'name': 'name1'}
{'name': 'name1'}
{'name': 'name1'}
{'name': 'name1'}
{'name': 'name1'}
```

How can I get it to parse name2 and the text inside the tag?

Answer (score 1):

`vars.text` should give you the text inside the variable element.

Also, `item.find('variable')` is only going to find the first variable. You can use `findall()` and iterate over the list that's returned.

I would also recommend not using `vars` as a variable name; it shadows the built-in name `vars`.

Here's an example...

```py
for item in root.findall('listitem'):
    for var_elems in item.findall('variable'):
        print(var_elems.attrib, var_elems.text)
```

prints...

```
{'name': 'name1'} text1
{'name': 'name2'} text2
{'name': 'name1'} text3
{'name': 'name2'} text4
```